# method of UIView calling from UIViewcontroller problem?

Tags: iphone

i have done the following...tran is a UIView...doSomething is a methos in UIView.but i cant
call that method from viewdidload? any help please?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 

tran *m_view = [[tran alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:m_view];
[m_view release];
tran *s = (tran *)self.view;
[s doSomthing];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1. Your subclass of `UIView` should be capitalized to `Tran` for readability (class names are capitalized)
2. You are adding `m_view` to the view controller's view via `-addSubview:`
3. Therefore, the view controller view has a `subviews` array, and that array contains an object instance of type `Tran *`
4. However, neither using `-addSubview:` nor casting via `(Tran *)` makes the view controller view of type `Tran`.
5. The view controller's view is still of type `UIView`
6. Therefore, you cannot call `Tran`'s `-doSomething` on the view controller's view, because that view is not of type `Tran`

Comment: tran is a UIView page ,dynaimcally i have created...tran.m file inwhich drawRect(which will be called automatically) method is available....how can i call any other methods from  view controller..?
any solution please?

Comment: You need to instantiate the view controller's view itself (not a subview) as an instance of type `Tran`. This can be done in `-viewDidLoad:` or in Interface Builder.